# CPLEX Constraints written in C++ not passed to model

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cplex

I do have quite an intense and indeed annoying problem. I implemented a MIP in C++ by using CPLEX. It compiles properly and even solves optimal. Always with the same result: Optimal Value of zero and all variables get the value zero. I do not simply not understand why.

I discovered that constraints are not active or working by the well-known stock balance equality of production theory.
I implemented that like this:

```
    for(int k=0;k++;k<nProducts){
    for(int t=1;t<=T;t++){
        model.add(y[k][t-1]+q[k][t]-y[k][t] - d[k][t-1] == 0);
    }
    }
```

Here nProducts is an integer (number of Products), T is the number of periods (also an integer).
y[k][t-1] is a float variable initialized as follows (the stock variable):

```
NumVarMatrix y(env,nProducts);
for(int i=0;i<nProducts;i++){
    y[i] = IloNumVarArray(env,T+1);
    for(int k=0;k<=T;k++){
    y[i][k] = IloNumVar(env,0.0,IloInfinity,ILOFLOAT);
    }
}
```

q[k][t] is also a float variable, the production quantity variable, initialized like that:

```
    NumVarMatrix q(env,nProducts);
for(int i=0;i<nProducts;i++){
    q[i] = IloNumVarArray(env,T+1);
    for(int k=0;k<T+1;k++){
    q[i][k] = IloNumVar(env,0.0,IloInfinity,ILOFLOAT);
    }
}
```

Does anyone has any idea what the problem is ? In fact I can even just cout the constraints for all k and t in the end and I will see that there are differences all the time.

Comment: Do you have an objective function?  Did you do an exportModel to see what constraints were actually added?

Comment: @DavidNehme Yes, I do have an objective function, it minimizes a weighted sum of the y variables. The exportModel has the objective and all the other constraints, but the not the above ones.

Comment: The constraints you show are missing aren't violated by an all 0 solution, so there are issues with your code other than these missing constraints.

Comment: Just throwing it out there, since all I've done is using Java but shouldn't
`model.add(y[k][t-1]+q[k][t]-y[k][t] - d[k][t-1] == 0);`be `model.addEq(model.sum(y{k][t-1],q[k][t],model.prod(-1,y[k][t]),model.prod(-1,d[k][t-q]),0);`?